# get the boundaries of a plot and plot the boundaries over the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python and I have a question of how to get the boundaries of a figure that plotted by matplotlib imshow. For example, the following figure is the one that plotted by imshow and I want to get the coordinate of the boundaries and plot the boundaries over the same image. I hope you can help me.

[image]

Here is the code that I wrote for the first two lines.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\t')
plt.imshow(df,origin='lower')
```

The stackoverflow does not allow me upload the raw data. But please download it from my google drive folder:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZPxtAz7vjsdFjeRmfop2cgpfcuGlO5PI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide the data? What do you mean by "boundaries"? The absolute limit of your data (looks like 0-44 on both axes), or the limit of values above a threshold? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi mozway, thanks for your comments. The boundary means the red line show in the above figure. Let me upload the raw data.

Comment: I just uploaded the raw data file into the google drive folder.

Comment: Is one of my [proposed solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503653/16343464) working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you original array:

[image: input]

One option is to compute a threshold on your array and then calculate the difference between the binary dilation and the threshold:

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation
array_thresh = np.array(array<0.8, dtype='int')
plt.imshow(binary_dilation(array_thresh)-array_thresh)
```

[image: binary dilation]

To perform the overlay, you need to mask the second array with [numpy.ma.masked_where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html):

```
a_cnt = (binary_dilation(a_thresh)-a_thresh)
a_cnt_masked = np.ma.masked_where(a_cnt==0, a_cnt)
plt.imshow(array)
plt.imshow(a_cnt_masked, cmap='hsv', interpolation='none')
```

[image: overlay]

You can also use a specialized library, such as [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html):

```
import cv2
im = cv2.threshold(array, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cnt = cv2.findContours(im.astype('uint8'), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
im2 = sum([cv2.drawContours(np.zeros(array.shape), [c], 0, (255,0,0), 1) for c in cnt])
plt.imshow(im2)
```

You might need to play around with the different parameters of opencv.

[image: contour]